# The absense of <html> opening tag, does it have any sense?

Tags: html, tags, google-calendar-api

In any other case I'd say this is an error, but in case of google maybe I'm wrong?

If you simply open the home page at https://www.google.com/calendar/render, after authentication of course, and check its source, you'll surprisingly see

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><head><title>Google Calendar</title><meta ....
```

Does it make any sense? I hope not, or in opposite case I should start attending the HTML class again :)

Should it be

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><title>Google Calendar</title><meta ....
```

for HTML5 opening tag?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opening `<html>` elements is optional, if the first tag after is *not* a comment:

> An html element’s start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside the html element is not a comment.

[W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/html.html#html)

The HTML parser will insert it implicitly like many other elements, most notably `<tbody>`, which is only rarely set explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The text between `<html>` and `</html>` explains the webpages; the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declares the doctype for HTML5.